# Kotlin try statement not working when specifying if without else

Tags: kotlin, if-statement, try-catch

Why would this piece of Kotlin code not compile? Needless to say return type is Unit (or void in Java)

The error is: **'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression**

```
    fun test() =
        try {
            if (true) {

            }
            // no else clause
        } finally {
            print("")
        }
```

It doesn't matter which combination of the try statement I implement (try with catch or try with finally or all of them)

```
    fun test() =
        try {
            if (true) {

            }
            // no else clause
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            print("")
        } finally {
            print("")
        }
```

**Strangely this compiles**:

```
    fun test() =
        try {
            if (true) {

            }
            print("print something")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            print("")
        } finally {
            print("")
        }
```

Using latest IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3):

`try/catch/finally`, `when`, and `if/else` can be used either as a statement or as an expression. When used as an expression, they have to return something. You are forcing the compiler to treat it as an expression by putting `=` in front of it.

You return something in `try/catch` by making it the last thing in your `try` block and in any `catch` blocks.

`if` by itself cannot be an expression. It has to be followed by `else` to be an expression.

Since the `if` block is the last thing in your `try` clause of your try/catch expression, it has to be an expression, because the last thing in the block represents what it returns.

The compiler is complaining because the last thing in your try/catch expression's try block is not an *expression*. It's an if *statement*.

When you add `println()` at the end, that's an *expression*, so it can be interpreted fine by the compiler. `println()` evaluates to Unit.

As @Gidds says in the comment below, the whole issue stems from making this a expression in the first place. If you have nothing useful to return (Unit), then make it a statement so you don't have to worry about pleasing the compiler. When you try to make it an expression, the compiler is pedantic because it's trying to prevent you from writing something that doesn't make sense to write if you're trying to return something useful.

Also, if you deliberately express that your expression should evaluate to Unit using `: Unit =`, then the compiler doesn't enforce that it really has to evaluate as an expression.

Comment: So doing a ```print("")``` in the finally block still doesn't make it work. Why does the compiler not allow an expression in the finally block?

Comment: The finally block is not a branch of try/catch. It's sort of like using `also`. It's evaluated after the try/catch. `finally` is intended for clean-up, not producing a result.

Comment: I understand. Still think is peculiar because adding else {} fixes it too. I think the compiler can actually be smart enough to understand this, right?

Comment: What's it supposed to understand? How can it guess what you intend when you don't put any expression to return from try? Kotlin very strongly supports the idea of presenting the *least astonishment* so it does not make assumptions on your behalf. A compiler error here alerts you to the fact that you did something you probably didn't intend because it doesn't make logical sense.

Comment: It can safely translate an ```if``` statement without an ```else``` branch to ```else {}```, I suppose. I know this is a mess and will and should never be done in a compiler, though.

Comment: The design philosophy with Kotlin is not to make assumptions like that. if without else is  defined to be a statement, not an expression. By showing a compile error it forces you to take a second look and make sure your code means what you intend. Kotlin also doesn't do implicit number conversions like Java does. You have to manually use `toInt()`, `toFloat()`, etc. And they are actually making `when` statements *more* strict in the next version. `when` with a subject will always be treated like an expression so the compiler will demand that you have an else branch.

Comment: @user1275645 May I draw your attention to the third sentence of this answer: “You are forcing the compiler to treat it as an expression by putting = in front of it.” I think that's the real issue here. If you use an expression body like this, and don't specify the return type, then the compiler has to _infer_ the return type — but it can't do so in this case. If you don't want your function to return anything useful, then either specify `: Unit` explicitly, or use the normal `{ … }` style body.